# Can I store a handful of constant complex objects in an enum-like structure in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application to work with data from an API that has a couple of different endpoints for different geographical regions. Each region has a name, an alphanumeric ID and a host URL. e.g.: `Western Europe - WE1 - we.api.com`.

There are less than a dozen regions and their values won't change, though regions might get added or removed in the future. I would like to store these in a maintainable way so that I can easily pass them as parameters to functions. e.g.: `GetUserData("username", Region.WesternEurope, true)`.

I have used Enums for this before for APIs where endpoints were defined by a single value but I can't decide how to go about this. One option I've considered is creating an Enum with just the names and then mapping those to objects in a dictionary in a static class, but I'm not a very experienced programmer and I don't know if this would be a good idea.

Comment: Let's not forget that you can do data annotations on Enums on C#, do you can add "extra data" to each enum. That being said, I think ChrisW's answer is the best for  you so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do that like this:

```cs
class Region
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public string id { get; private set; }
    public string url { get; private set; }

    // private constructor
    Region() {}

    // static members
    public static Region WesternEurope = new Region() {
        name = "Western Europe",
        id = "WE1",
        url = "we.api.com"
    };
}
```

I think that the private constructor implies that instances can only be created from within the class, e.g. as static members, so you control what instances are created.

---

Eventually you could load the instances from an external source (data file, database, or registry).

Per Doc Brown's comment, below, you could implement this loading in a static constructor of the Region class (e.g. to load all regions), or implement such loading in a static get accessor as shown below (e.g. to load each region just in time, if and when it's accessed).

---

In a comment below, Rumen Georgiev suggested the following alternative (which is, IMO, more complicated, and unnecessary, and not thread-safe):

```
// static members
private static Region _westernEurope;
public static Region WesternEurope 
{
    get 
    {
        if (_westernEurope == null)
        {
            _westernEurope = new Region() 
            {
                name = "Western Europe",
                id = "WE1",
                url = "we.api.com"
            };
        }
        return _westernEurope;
    }
}
```

---

An alternative version, which is both thread-safe and still enables lazy initialization of `WesternEurope`, uses the `Lazy<>` type:

```
    private static Lazy<Region> _westernEurope = new Lazy<Region>(
        () => new Region() 
        {
            name = "Western Europe",
            id = "WE1",
            url = "we.api.com"
        });

    public static Region WesternEurope => _westernEurope.Value;
```

It's questionable whether this is worth doing in this case though as the overhead of creating the instances when `Region` is statically initialised is likely to be small.

Comment: Good answer, but it could be even better by mentioning static constructors, where loading of the external instances could be implemented.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than I thought was possible!

Comment: This way every time any of the static properties is accessed new instance of `Region` will be created. It's better to have a single instance for each property (with lazy initialization) to reduce memory consumption and GC overhead. Also, think about comparing objects by reference (e.g. `Region.WesternEurope != Region.WesternEurope`)

Comment: I have changed the code in the answer to illustrate better solution.

Comment: @RumenGeorgiev `This way every time any of the static properties is accessed new instance of Region will be created.` That's not true: all the static instances are created once, when the Region class is first referenced (as if they were constructed by a static constructor of Region). It would be true if I were returning `new` from inside a `get` property (because a `get` property'a code is re-run each time it's accessed).

Comment: I have updated @RumenGeorgiev's additions to use `Lazy<Region>`, as this is a thread-safe way of doing lazy initialisation.

Comment: @DavidArno Could you preserve the previous code and append yours, please, to better explain the incremental change?

Comment: @ChrisW, Good point. I've added Rumen's suggestion back in.

Comment: @DavidArno I think that the second `=>`, on the last line, should be a `=` instead. Also I haven't used `Lazy` but I guess that `WesternEurope` needs to be a `get` property rather than a static data member, so that `_westernEurope.Value` isn't fetched until just-in-time, rather than immediately.

Comment: Going off your first method, would it make more sense to be a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Comment: @Bobson I wondered that. Maybe yes, because it's intended as a replacement for Enum, and Enum is a value type; and a class instead can be `null` whereas a struct instance (is a value type and) cannot be null. However you can't prevent the default constructor on a struct, so anyone could call `new Region()` to create an empty Region instance.

Comment: Users could also have a Region data member of their class, which they forget to initialize. If Region is a class then that member would be null, if Region were a struct then it would be an empty struct ... not much better. And defensively detecting an empty struct (if it's passed in as a parameter) might be less easy than detecting null.

Answer (score 0):

The answer all depends on your requirements over time.

If your only requirement is clean code that's easy to understand, I would suggest a straight forward class like this:

```
internal static class regionStrings {

  static public string Ireland { get; private set; }

  static regionStrings()
  {
    Ireland = "eu-west-1";
  }
}
```

Comment: This would  mean any method that took a region would how have to take a string